# HTML5 canvas scripting ignored

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am missing something likely painfully obvious. The only reason why I can find a canvas using "inspect element" is because it was declared when its id was attributed. The JavaScript is blatantly ignored. I've tried various commands on the canvas context; nothing happens. Help would be greatly appreciated. Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">        
<header>
    <canvas id="title_canvas" width: "1200px"; height: "100px"></canvas>
    <script>
        var title_c = document.getElementByID("title_canvas");
        var title_ctx = document.getContext("2d");
        title_ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,90);
    </script>       
</header>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed some errors : http://jsbin.com/ejanif/1/edit

Comment: Did you look at the console ? You would have seen some of the errors.

Comment: Did you even try to find the mistake by yourself ?

Comment: Using Aptana Studio 3, no mistakes were indicated.

Comment: Well you can throw that software to the bin.

Comment: Geesh no need to get snappy Virus721, I've been busy with another program for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `getContext` on the canvas, not the document.

Comment: Ah ok wow man I think I should just take a break. Going to delete question now ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is what it should be:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">        
<header>
    <canvas id="title_canvas" width: "1200px" height: "100px"></canvas>
    <script>
        var title_c = document.getElementById("title_canvas");
        var title_ctx = title_c.getContext("2d");
        title_ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,90);
    </script>       
</header>   
</div>
</body>
```

The getContext is a canvas method not a document method. You also had a stray semicolon in your HTML.